# How to do calculations within an undefined list

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to take specific numbers within a list to calculate them but am not sure where to start. For example if we have a empty list, list = [] and then we call the list in the future with the user input numbers to definition def example(list):. How can I take a1, b1, a2, b2, etc.. from that list? I will need to calculate different calculations (a1 - b1 + a2 - b2 and so on) .

The numbers within the list is undefined until a user inputs how ever many numbers they wish. I will need to use all of the user inputed numbers

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: To reference a specific element from a list, you can either loop through the list with a for each loop, or you can do `list[i]` where `i` is the number of the element.

Comment: How do you know which ones should be added and which should be subtracted?

Comment: @Barmar, that’s what im asking. The user will give the program numbers, so it’s an undefined list until the user fills out the numbers

Comment: That's not what I asked -- how does the user specify whether it should be `+ b1` or `- b1`?

Comment: @Bomar, I’m trying to figure out how to take two lists of numbers that’s the same length and return the inner product.

Comment: Use `itertools.product()`

Comment: That's not what your example does, though.

Comment: @Barmar, we can assume that it will go in the order a1 -(minus) b1 + a2 - b2 + a3 - b3 etc

Comment: I don't see the pattern. It's not alternating adding and subtracting.

Comment: Your `example()` function only takes one list as the parameter, not two lists.

Comment: I edited my comment

Comment: Put the clarification in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Thanks, just made it more clarified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the list, and check whether the element index is odd or even. Add the even elements, subtract the odd elements.

```
def alternate_add_subtract(l):
    total = 0
    for index, val in enumerate(l):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            total += val
        else:
            total -= val
    return total
```

Or if you're getting two lists, use `zip()` to iterate over them in parallel:

```
def add_and_subtract(l1, l2):
    return sum(a - b for a, b in zip(l1, l2))
```